# Addition with Session variables

Tags: php, session, post

I'm trying to pass through a session variable the sum of 2 values from 2 different text boxes. This may be a silly question but I can't figure it out.

```
$_SESSION["session-price"] = $_POST["price" + "sizePrice"];
```

Comment: `<?php session_start(); $price=$_POST['price']; $sizePrice=$_POST['sizePrice']; $_SESSION["session-price"] = $price + $sizePrice;`

Comment: [**Try this demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#xCPJTVy56) press `ctrl+enter` to run it; you'll see my above example works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it right now, PHP is interpreting your code as follows:

```
$_SESSION["session-price"] = $_POST[0];
```

because when you attempt to perform mathematical functions on strings, PHP will attempt to interpret them as integers. Because there is nothing contained within those strings that could be evaluated to a real integer, they will both evaluate to zero. [You can see this in action here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#8jOFpnsU8) (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to run).

---

```
$_SESSION["session-price"] = $_POST["price"] + $_POST["sizePrice"];
```

will yield the result you are expecting. You must declare them as two separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

They're two separate variables:

```
$_SESSION["session-price"] = $_POST["price"] + $_POST["sizePrice"];
```

Comment: [`This would work too`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188783/addition-with-session-variables#comment39223304_25188783) assuming OP's form elements are named. Gawd, I never put in answers for questions like these. But, this is indeed the correct method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Indeed it would.

Comment: Oh well, we can't win 'em all. You did get a "dime" out of me though ;)

Comment: Great! You've got a 1930's model? They cost us 4 bits today; inflation.